# what is a left nilpotent Leibniz algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let consider $L$ be a Leibniz algebra which is left nilpotent. ( I do not know what is left nilpotent of class 3).

A Leibniz algebra L is said to be nilpotent, if for lower central series there exists n ∈ N such that $L^{n} = 0$. The minimal number $n$ with this property is said to be index of nilpotency of algebra $L$. Is the class of nilpotency the same with index of nilpotency?

An n-dimensional Leibniz algebra is called null filiform if $dim L^{i}=n+1-i$, where $1 \leq i \leq n+1$. Is a left nilpotent Leibniz algebra of class 3 a null filiform Leibniz algebras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algebra $A$ is called *left* Leibniz, if its multiplication satisfies the left Leibniz identity
$$
(ab) c = a (bc) − b (ac)
$$
for all $a, b, c ∈ A$. The $2$-sided ideals $A^i$ and $A_i$ are defined by $A^1=A$ and $A^{i+1}=AA^i$, and $A_1=A$, $A_{i+1}=\sum_{p=1}^iA_pA_{i+1-p}$,
from the left. Then $A$ is called *left nilpotent* if $A_n=0$ for some $n$.  One can show that $A_n=A^n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: So the index of nilpotency is the same with the class of nilpotency? Since in some papers I saw these two words!

Comment: Yes, it is the same.

Comment: According to your detailed definition,  we can say that a left nilpotent Leibniz of class 3 is null filiform, am I right?

Comment: What dimension has your Leibniz algebra of class $3$?

Comment: In fact, we have a variety of Leibniz algebras satisfying a special polynomial identity in such a way the Leibniz algebras satisfying the identity are left nilpotent of class 3.